# exception returns whole coroutine scope body

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

so I was working `withcoroutines` and `ktor client` inside `viewModel` and I faced aproblem

```
    private val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable ->
        Log.i("SplashException", throwable.toString())
    }

    private fun chooseDestination() = viewModelScope.launch(
    context = Dispatchers.IO + exceptionHandler
    ) {
    val password = dataStoreRepository.readPassword()
    val phoneNumber = dataStoreRepository.readPhoneNumber()

    if (password == null || phoneNumber == null) {
        _destinationRoute.emit(RouteBuilder.signInScreen())
        return@launch
        }

    val isUserAuthenticated = authDao.signIn(
        requestModel = SignInRequestModel(
            phone = phoneNumber,
            password = password
            )
        )
    _destinationRoute.emit(
        if (isUserAuthenticated)
            RouteBuilder.homeScreen()
        else
            RouteBuilder.signInScreen()
        )
    }
```

when I call `authDao.signIn()` method, if server returns error, the rest of method stucks and won't get called.
here is `authDao.signIn()`:

```
    suspend fun signIn(
    requestModel: SignInRequestModel
    ): Boolean {
        val response = httpClient.post(
            urlString = "http://someHost:8080/api/v1/user/signIn",
            block = {
                setBody(requestModel)
            }
        )
        return response.status.value in 200..299
    }
```

how can I solve this

Comment: "the rest of method stucks and won't get called" --> The rest of the method is just the `emit` call. Are you saying it just doesn't emit? How are you determining the rest of the method doesn't run? By the way, there's no reason to specify Dispatchers.IO here because you aren't calling any blocking functions.

Comment: @Tenfour04 `authDao` is a suspend function.
and `destinationRoute.emit()` dosnt work if i get error

Comment: I would expect it simply throws an exception and this is why it never emits. How do you know it doesn't throw, you don't see the log?